# C++ issue with lambda function

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, unreal-engine4

So I have a map with a key as a string, and I want to sort that map by the first value in the strings.

I want to sort the strings like this:

```
10 - 20
40 - 50
60 - 80
200 - 400
420+
```

I have a couple of more maps that I sort alphabetically. But this doesn't work for this case, because it would sort on the first letter, so it will become:

```
10 - 20
200 - 400
40 - 50
60 - 80
420+
```

Which I obviously do not want.

I normally sort like this:

```
dropdowncategory.KeySort([](const string& A, const string& B) {
    return A.Compare(B, ESearchCase::IgnoreCase) < 0;
});
```

Simple.

But in this case from the A and B I want to get the first number, convert it to int and sort on that.

So what I did is I wrote a function (Not able to test it yet, but it should get the first number from the string, this is not the problem.):

```
int GetIntFromString(string s) {
    int value = 0;
    string L, R;
    if (s.Contains("-")) {
        s.Split("-", &L, &R);
    }
    else{
        s.Split("+", &L, &R);
    }
    value = FCString::Atoi(*L); 
    return value;
}
```

From this function I will get the first number in the string. Then I want to sort on that outcome.

What I tried is the following:

```
dropdowncategory.KeySort([](const string& A,const string& B) {
    return GetIntFromString(A) < GetIntFromString(B);
});
```

and:

```
string SA, SB;
dropdowncategory.KeySort([SA,SB](string& A, string& B) {
    return GetIntFromString(SA) < GetIntFromString(SB);
});
```

But I keep getting and error on the GetIntFromString function in the return value of the KeySort:

Error (active)  an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list.

I am not sure why though.

I guess I cannot use that function inside the KeySort because it is a local function, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Wouldn't that get the same issue as the alphabetic sorting? Putting 200 in front of 30 for example.

Comment: Is `GetIntFromString` declared static?

Comment: Join the club. Everyone else is "not sure why", either. That's because the shown code fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. What is `FString`? What is `AFilterManager`. Is `GetIntFromString` an ordinary class method, or a static class method? All of these could potentially cause a compilation error. You need to edit your question, and provide a [mcve] that anyone else can try to reproduce your exact compilation error.

Comment: No it is not declared static, might that be the problem?

Comment: It certainly could, but nobody can tell you for sure unless you provide a [mcve]. Without a proper [mcve] you, and everyone else, are just guessing, and wasting their time.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that, these are Unreal Engine 4 values, but that wouldn't be such an issue for a skilled developer to see past that I think.

Comment: I am not sure about `FString` but regular `atoi` or better `std::stoi` would work without splitting and staff.

Comment: A "skilled developer" will also understand that C++ is arguably the world's most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. As such, the question is far from providing complete information. A "skilled developer" will also understand exactly what information needs to be provided in this kind of a question that's posed to others who've never seen the code in question; in order for it to actually have complete information that everyone will need to reproduce the problem themselves. These kinds of question are generally not answerable, unless they're reproducible. Full stop.

Comment: @Slava as I commented I have not tested that part yet, or optimized it. Just added it so people would have an idea what that function is doing or should do

Comment: @AlexanderS. I am telling you that you overcomplicated the issue, remove your pesky `GetIntFromString` and just use `std::stoi` - it will convert to number until it meets unconvertable symbol ('-' or '+' or ' ') this is what you need.

Comment: @Slava thanks will give that a try, didn't know it could do that!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in `std::stoi` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

> Discards any whitespace characters (as identified by calling isspace()) until the first non-whitespace character is found, **then takes as many characters as possible to form a valid base-n (where n=base) integer number representation** and converts them to an integer value.

(emphasis is mine) it does what you need already, so your lambda can be just:

```
dropdowncategory.KeySort([](const string& A,const string& B) {
    return std::stoi(A) < std::stoi(B);
});
```

note, converting string to integer is not very simple operation so you may want to reorganize your data so you do not have to do it for that strings so many times.

Comment: Thanks will try this and try to optimize it too.

Comment: If you have 5 items as shown in your example then do not bother to optimize.

Comment: A well in that case, I wont, because it wont be more then 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FString SA, SB;
dropdowncategory.KeySort([SA,SB](FString& A, FString& B) {
    return GetIntFromString(SA) < GetIntFromString(SB);
});
```

Here you have 2 local string vars, empty (I suppose, no idea what's `FString`). You provide a lambda as a sorting function. *Usually* such function should have signature `bool(const Key& left, const Key& right)`, and your lambda *almost* satisfied this requirement (pay attention to `const`). `left` and `right` here will be two keys to compare, and you need to define this comparison to define your sorting order. So correct version would be:

```
dropdowncategory.KeySort([](const FString& A, const FString& B) {
    return GetIntFromString(A) < GetIntFromString(B);
});
```

This still doesn't explain your error, mainly because I have no idea what the error is.

By the way, `GetIntFromString` should be a free function, or at least a static member function, because its implementation depends only on input parameters.

P.S. listen to @Slava in the question comments, which can lead to

```
dropdowncategory.KeySort([](const FString& A, const FString& B) {
    return std::atoi(*A) < std::atoi(*B);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining FString, I always work in UE4 and it has it's own type of string values. Also sometimes other values can be different so it is not always clear how I would have to write that in "normal" C++

I will see if that helps, UE4 uses C++ but is sometimes doing stuff just different, which is also confusing for me sometimes.

Comment: UE4 doesn't use standard library, like stuff in `std` namespace, but C++ itself is the same compiled by same popular compilers. Next time you have a problem, specify `UE4` tag or to get better/faster help - try to provide a minimal verifiable example substituting UE4 specific types by standard ones

Answer (score 0):

You can try to express your intent: treat the entries as pairs of ints, and use existing sorting logic for that:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> pairs;
std::transform(begin(dropdowncategory), end(dropdowncategory),
  std::back_inserter(pairs),
  [](auto s){
     std::stringstream ss(s);
     int i; ss >> i;
     char dummy; ss >> dummy;
     int j; ss >> j;
     return std::make_tuple(i, j);
  });
std::sort(begin(pairs), end(pairs)); // 30, 50 will come before 200, 210

// convert pairs back to strings?
```